# finding exact value of $\sec^{-1} 5$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

> Find the exact value of $\sec^{-1} 5$ (decimal answer).

I know that $\sec^{-1}5=\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1}{5}$, but I don't know how to proceed from here. I drew a right triangle with sides $1$ and $5$ and used the Pythagorean Theorem to find the other side, which is $2\sqrt{6}$. The answer is $1.37$.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint, let $\arccos\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) = \theta$ for some angle $|\theta|\leq 1$. Then we have $\frac{1}{5}=\cos\theta$.

Comment: @Gahawar I know, but what do I do from there? thanks

Comment: You're not going to find the exact value as a rational multiple of $\pi$, if that's what you're looking for. The only rational values assumed by $\sin$ and $\cos$ at rational multiples of $\pi$ are $0$, $\pm 1$, and $\pm\frac12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't find the exact decimal answer.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%281%2F5%29) gives $1.369438406004565827776196139422128031858546618285324524230221\dots $
radians.  If you need to compute it without a calculator that has inverse trig functions, you are in for some work.  Probably the easiest approach is $\arccos \frac 15 = \frac \pi 2 - \arcsin \frac 15$, then use $\sin x \approx x-\frac {x^3}6$ to approximate $x$.  An iteration $(x_0=\frac 15, x_{i+1}=\frac 15+\frac 16x_i^3$)quickly converges to $x \approx 0.201361$, giving $\arccos \frac 15 \approx 1.369436$